# Kafka uncommitted messages

Tags: apache-kafka

Lets say the partition has 4 replicas (1 leader, 3 followers) and all are currently in sync. `min.insync.replicas` is set to 3 and `request.required.acks` is set to all or -1.

The producer send a message to the leader, the leader appends it to it's log. After that, two of the replicas crashed before they could fetch this message. One remaining replica successfully fetched the message and appended to it's own log.

The leader, after certain timeout, will send an error (NotEnoughReplicas, I think) to the producer since min.insync.replicas condition is not met.

My question is: what will happen to the message which was appended to leader and one of the replica's log?

Will it be delivered to the consumers when crashed replicas come back online and broker starts accepting and committing new messages (i.e. high watermark is forwarded in the log)?

Answer (score 8):

If there is no min.insync.replicas available and producer uses ack=all, then the message is not committed and consumers will not receive that message, even after crashed replicas come back and are added to the ISR list again. You can test this in the following way.

Start two brokers with min.insync.replicas = 2

```
$ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server-1.properties
$ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server-2.properties
```

Create a topic with 1 partition and RF=2. Make sure both brokers are in the ISR list.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --create --topic topic1 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 2
Created topic "topic1".
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --describe --topic topic1
Topic:topic1    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
        Topic: topic1   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
```

Run console consumer and console producer. Make sure produce uses ack=-1

```
$ ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092 --topic topic1
$ ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092 --topic topic1 --request-required-acks -1
```

Produce some messages. Consumer should receive them.

Kill one of the brokers (I killed broker with id=2). Check that ISR list is reduced to one broker.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper-1 --describe --topic topic1
Topic:topic1    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
       Topic: topic1    Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1
```

Try to produce again. In the producer you should get some

```
Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS
```

(one per retry) and finally

```
Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required.
```

Consumer will not receive these messages.

Restart the killed broker and try to produce again.
Consumer will receive these message but not those that you sent while one of the replicas was down.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the watermark will not advance until both failed
follow-broker recovered and caught up.

See this blog post for more details: http://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/

Comment: So the message will ultimately be delivered to consumers, even though the broker did not acknowledge the same to the producer.

Comment: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Error observerd
Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required.

To resolve this i had increase the number of replication factors and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).